# Beautiful soup and extracting values

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I would be gretful if you could give me some guidance on how I would grab the date of birth "16 June 1723" below while using beautifulsoup. Now using my code I have managed to grab the values which you see below under results however all what I need is to only grab the value 16 June 1723. any advice?

My code:

```
birth = soup.find("table",{"class":"infobox"})

test = birth.find(text='Born')

next_cell = test.find_parent('th').find_next_sibling('td').get_text()

print next_cell
```

Result:

```
16 June 1723 NS (5 June 1723 OS)Kirkcaldy, Scotland,Great Britain
```

Comment: Your  data might be more easily extracted from a child tag present in the `td` tag. Would it be possible to show the HTML of that table?

Comment: <th scope="row" style="text-align:left;padding-right:0.6em;">Born</th>

Comment: <th scope="row" style="text-align:left;padding-right:0.6em;">Born</th>
<td>16 June 1723 <a href="/wiki/New_Style" title="New Style" class="mw-redirect">NS</a><br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of last print statement, add this

```
print ' '.join(str(next_cell).split()[:3])
```